# SQL View Update

Tags: php, mysql

I have a program with an SQL View that is slow in loading. I'm trying to figure out why and I was thinking that the view is updated every time the site is hit. Or is it updated just when the view itself is hit?

Comment: MySQL views are not "updated". They are live queries, so if the query that composes the view is poorly optimized, the view will always be slow.  MySQL doesn't have support for materialized views.

Comment: If you post the query, we may be able to offer assistance in optimizing it.

Comment: Is it the view query only run when I try to pull data from it?  Because the page in question doesn't need or use the view. Does that rule it out as a possibility for the slow response?

Comment: The view only runs when you select from it. If it isn't actively used or joined against on a page load, then yes that pretty much rules it out as your problem.

Comment: Michael is right: you should cache query results if you don't want the query to run every time. You should think of a view as a query with a table interface for access data.

Comment: Could the slow response be to running the app on a local wampserver, but the database is at a remote site?

Comment: @TheHawk Yes, that is very likely a cause. If there is a slow DNS response between the web host and the remote server, it could increase response times by several seconds. Do a traceroute to the mysql host to see if its hanging up somewhere.

Comment: And BTW you are likely exchanging lots of data from and to the remote database.